# Get hash key and convert into string ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Example Hash

```
hash = {:key => ["val1", "val2]}
```

When I did this on rails 3.0.7, it was fine.

```
> hash.keys.to_s
 => "key"
> hash[hash.keys.to_s]
 => ["val1", "val2"]
```

But if I do this with rails 3.1.3, it isn't.

```
> hash.keys.to_s
 => [\"key\"]
> hash[hash.keys.to_s]
 => nil
```

**Is this was because of the Rails version changed?** and **Is there any other way to turn hash key into a string that works with both version (or with rails 2 too)?**

Comment: Fwiw, the current behavior is more correct, and the answe is largely self-evident: "keys" is plural, and should be a collection.

Comment: Yes Dave, I should notice that. Thanks for the reminder !!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Did you upgrade Ruby as well as Rails?  I think this is a change between 1.8 and 1.9

Try `hash.keys.first.to_s` (if there's always only one key) or `hash.keys.join`

Comment: Ahh, yes. I forgot to told you that they was 1.8.7@rails307 and 1.9.2@rails313

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to convert it to a symbol instead of a string which is being more correct:

```
hash[hash.keys.to_sym]
```

Comment: Thx for answer but its not working on Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1.3. hash.keys.to_sym will shown and error, undefined method 'to_sym' for [:key]:Array